# How to tell which php.ini files is loaded ?

Tags: php

Looking at my `php.info`, all it says is "Loaded Configuration file: C:\xampp\php\php.ini."

Yet I have two ini files inside the PHP folder, one "development", and the other "production."

I can not see within either ini file the value, "Loaded Configuration file."

So, how do I tell which one is being used and where it is managed?

My goal is to have only one ini file and disable the other.

Comment: What platform are you running on? It's possible there's a symlink from php.ini to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

just rename the one you want to keep to C:\xampp\php\php.ini. You can keep other ini files along, php will just use the one at C:\xampp\php\php.ini.